# Identify Mandarin word - "kiāng"

Tags: mandarin, slang, taiwan, zhuyin-fuhao

Have seen this word in video comments and cannot find a reference for it anywhere??

Some details:

- Always rendered in zhuyin (ㄎㄧㄤ) even in otherwise ideographic text
- Doesn't appear to be a native Mandarin syllable (Taiwanese loanword?)
- Appears to be gamer slang (frequently appears on game screencasts)
- Can seemingly be randomly inserted into otherwise valid sentences with no apparent change in meaning?

Answer (score 4):

As can be gleaned from the fact that it is usually represented in Zhuyin, ㄎㄧㄤ is a bit of slang used primarily in Taiwan, especially among young people.

ㄎ with ㄧ (or k + i in Pinyin) is not a legitimate combination of sounds for modern Mandarin, so it's not likely to have originated there.

Its primary meaning is hard to pin down, but "goofy" (see for example [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/taiwan/comments/3tj236/my_taiwanesemandarin_slang_is_from_the_90s_what/) but also its use in [this blog name](http://kiangrenriji.blogspot.com/)), "tipsy", "dazed", "in awe" are all possible interpretations. The images on this [AppleDaily post](https://tw.appledaily.com/new/realtime/20150908/686711/) might be helpful.

This [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/taiwan/comments/3tj236/my_taiwanesemandarin_slang_is_from_the_90s_what/) thread suggests that it is not a feature of older Taiwanese people, and probably does not come from the Taiwanese varieties of Minnan (i.e. Hokkien). However, this sound (in a high level tone) does exist in Taiwanese, meaning "to steal or snatch". Dictionaries generally [write it as 勍](https://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/result_detail.jsp?n_no=5808&curpage=1&sample=khiang&radiobutton=1&querytarget=1&limit=20&pagenum=1&rowcount=3); it is also written as 鏘 by [some sources](https://www.nownews.com/news/20160530/2116744/). Whether this could have conceivably been extended to the meanings of this slang term - that is something less well defined.